# BHS inscription between Psalms and Job

Tags: hebrew-bible

What is the significance of the inscription in the Biblia Hebraica Stuttgartensia between the Psalter and the book of Job and what is the proper translation?

[image: Annotation after Psalm 150]

Answer (score 2):

The text in question is an end-note by an editor, fairly typical of printed editions of [Biblia Hebraica Stuttgartensia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblia_Hebraica_Stuttgartensia). Thanks to a friend whose Hebrew is fluent (mine is not), I learned that the meaning is quite straightforward. It refers to the Book of Psalms. It simply summarizes the number of verses and sections:

- sum of the verses of [the] book
- two thousands and five hundred
- and twenty and seven
- and sections 19

The "sections" apparently refers to a reading schedule. Thanks to @Magicker72 at Mi Yodeya, I was able to discover what this means. It is an old division of the Hebrew Bible, no longer in use, into sections for scheduled reading.

> Tanach Yomi helpfully provides a [list](https://www.tanachyomi.co.il/PDFFiles/prakim.pdf) which includes the 19 sedarim
> [divisions] for Psalms, with starting points at: 1:1, 11:7, 20:10,
> 29:11, 35:28, 41:14, 49:19, 57:12, 67:8, 72:20, 78:38, 84:13, 90:17,
> 101:1, 105:45, 111:10, 119:72, 128:6, and 140:14.

Comment: Thank you Dan. Very helpful.

Comment: @edhuff - just making sure you saw my edit. The division of the Psalms into 19 sections is an old system no longer in use.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks Dan for researching this. I also like to 'drill down' to uncover meaning.